# How do i minify my js in my framework

Tags: php, javascript, minify, assetic

I have built a customized php framework.

I have a view, controllers and model.

In the view, there is variable which i can set.

```
$js = array('custom/testimonial.js','jquery.js');
```

At the footer view i have the following code.

```
-------------------------------------------------*/
if(isset($js)){
foreach ($js as $jsname) { ?>
<script src="<?php echo MAIN_URL; ?>/resources/js/<?php echo $jsname; ?>"></script>
<?php 
} 
}
```

Basically, the code in footer will load all the necessary scripts required for that page. In my other pages, i have other(different) javascripts files to include. This mean thats each page will have different javascript.

I would like to minify the js for each of the page and wonder which is the best way. I tried using Assetic (php asset management) with no luck.

Another question is should i minify javascript on the fly? Means when i load my page called testimonial.php it will check what are the javascript required for the page and minify them before displaying. Will that post performance issues even if i cache it.

I am looking for some methods that has high maintainability as i do not have to minifiy all javascript manually, have 40 to 50 plus pages. (each page uses different javascript files, plugins, lib).

Can Assetic do the job for me? Currently i have problems generating a static file for the javascript.

Appreciated any help.

Comment: Just look into configuring gzip on your server and you'll be fine without minification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo (YUI) used to have a compressor/ minifier, but they're now moving to UglifyJS. See:

- https://github.com/yui/yuglify
- https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/

There are also several online minification services, based on the YUI compressor.

- http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: Yep. Many libraries come with minified versions already, so you don't have to do those yourself. You can also make a tiny PHP function/ or tag to reference the JS files, which will switch between minimized & development versions automatically for you.

Comment: Just asking.. Did Other startups uses a manually method to compress js for each page? Or is there some kind of smart mechanism..

Comment: I am confused about the switching mechanism .. What is the logic behind it. Interested to explore it..

Comment: In Java, I like to use a ".properties" file to specify key application properties -- server address, mailserver, etc -- and I have a "development" flag in there as well. I don't deploy the properties file with the app -- it stays local to the server/ or local dev system. One of the things you can do, once you have a "development" switch, is make things easier for yourself :) You can presumably use a PHP file to do the same thing -- switch between minified and "debuggable" versions.

Comment: hi thomas, do you think minify is good? https://code.google.com/p/minify/ any idea how the implementation of it can cater to my scenario?

Comment: Looks good, why don't you give it a try? Having an on-demand service with caching simplifies both your development & deployment environments.. since you should be able to turn the whole thing on/off as needed. Good luck.